# Missing Custom values in PayPal IPN

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using PayPal name value pair for instant payment through our website. And I have set up a Custom field value and some times returning IPN missing the Custom values. It returns "&custom=&payer_status=unverified&" like this blank for custom field. And I really need that custom field to save in our database.

Can anyone give some solution on the same please

Comment: Custom field works for me and has for several years. I suspect the problem is elsewhere. Either you don't send it, or perhaps there's a character set issue or something. Maybe other fields (like the item name) includes the `&` sign? Have you tried logging all communication to and from PayPal? Perhaps something will stand out.

Comment: custom value is set in your API call, have you check the request made from your code?

Comment: Vilx, actually Custom field works for me too for nearly 5 years. Just for 1 transaction I received this missing parameter. It must have sent the Custom field from my website as the Custom field is the UserID, So without UserID, the page will kick the customer out when they click the Payment Now button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working after 2 days of continuous try. PayPal is upgrading their payment system.
we contacted PayPal technical support and they said IPN validation is failed due to encoding. So I had to go in PayPal profile and change "PayPal button language encoding" to UTF-8 as per their advice. And it is working now.

So following are the steps to change the encoding if someone else facing the same issue.

```
1.  Log into your PayPal account
2.  Go to your profile
3.  Look for the “PayPal button language encoding” section under the My 
    selling tools
4.  Make sure your website language is set to the correct language
5.  Click the more options button
6.  Make sure encoding is set to UTF-8
7.  Then save settings
```

You have to set the encoding to UTF-8 even though you did not create the button from PayPal.

> And one more thing we had to do was remove all leading and trailing spaces in the parameters as they don't support those spaces anymore.

Hope it helps you